# Liquibase is not recalculating MD5SUM from previous versions

Tags: java, sql, spring, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I've looked everywhere but I'm not able to find an answer to this. Because of some liquibase migration errors someone suggested to recalculate md5sum from the records in our databasechangelog. The only ones that are recalculated is from the latest version of liquibase. The others are just ignored. I'm still not sure if it has to do with this, but starting our application takes a lot longer now, since I cleared all checksums.

| # | ID | AUTHOR | FILENAME | DATEEXECUTED | ORDEREXECUTED | EXECTYPE | MD5SUM | DESCRIPTION | COMMENTS | TAG | LIQUIBASE | CONTEXTS | LABELS | DEPLOYMENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 526 | postalAddress-unique | test | classpath:/db/changelog/postal-address.xml | 2021-09-09 16:18:51 | 561 | EXECUTED |  | addUniqueConstraint tableName=postal_address |  |  | 3.10.3 |  |  | 1197131220 |
| 527 | Invitation-createTable | test | db/changelog/invitation.xml | 2021-09-29 10:44:53 | 563 | EXECUTED | 8:975a6aa7354504f9bfcc4c0a77a76af0 | createTable tableName=co_organizer_invitation |  |  | 4.3.5 |  |  | 2905092144 |

tldr; How do I force the md5sums to recalculate and should it affect the building process of the app if the md5sums are null?

FYI: We're using Java Spring with Liquibase

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums to null out the MD5SUM column and then the values will be recalculated on the next db update. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But after restarting the application only the MD5SUM of the latest version of liquibase were recalculated. The others were just left null. I could change all of these to the latest version, but I don't think that's the right thing to do. Any suggestions? Thanks!